# C++ POST request with cURL + JSON Lib

Tags: c++, json, c++11, curl

I would like to do a `POST` request using `cURL`. 
I am using [this](https://github.com/nlohmann) (github:nlohmann/json) library to handle my `JSON` object creation. I receive the `HTTP 200 Response`, but the `POST` data is not being appended.

When calling `std::cout<< json_data.dump() << std::endl;`
I receive a well-formed `JSON`.

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "c": "0",
            "d": "0",
            "e": "0",
            "f": "0",
            "g": "1506961983",
            "h": "1506961986",
            "i": "3"
        },
        {
            "c": "1",
            "d": "2",
            "e": "1",
            "f": "1",
            "g": "1506961987",
            "h": "1506961991",
            "i": "4"
        }
    ],
    "b": "test"
}
```

I use this to append my data.

```
   struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; 
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");  
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8"); 
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_data.dump().c_str());
```

Documentation [curl_easy_setopt documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html)

If I look into my AWS logs. It says:

```
{
  "format": "json",
  "payload": 5,
  "qos": 0,
  "timestamp": 1506961394810,
  "topic": "test_topic"
}
```

Why is it showing the value of **5** instead of my `JSON` object?

Thanks for help, if anyone knows why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On this line:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_data.dump().c_str());
```

The string object returned by `dump()` is temporary and destroyed when `curl_easy_setopt()` exits, thus leaving `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` with a dangling pointer that may or may not still be pointing to the JSON data in memory by the time libCURL tries to post it.

Per the [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html):

> The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes. This behaviour can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the [`CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html) option.

So, you need to either:

- change `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`:

  ```
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, json_data.dump().c_str());
  ```
- save the result of `json_data.dump()` to a local variable that does not go out of scope until after `curl_easy_perform()` exits:

  ```
  std::string json = json_data.dump();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
  ...
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and come back to you.

Comment: You saved me hours of testing and prevented me from going crazy... thanks!

Comment: You saved me. Thanks!